# How can I approximate wasabi taste?

Tags: substitutions, wasabi

I want to obtain a taste very similar to wasabi, but without wasabi ingredients. How do I do it?

Comment: are you looking for taste or heat?

Comment: @sarge What do You mean by heat?

Comment: It means the spicy taste.

Comment: @kiamlaluno yes, that.

Answer (score 9):

A good portion of the "wasabi" that you buy is a mixture of western horseradish, mustard, green food coloring, and occasionally, a token amount of actual wasabi.

So if that's the experience you're trying to replicate, use western freshly grated (or prepared) horseradish and a small amount of powdered mustard.

Having eaten fresh wasabi, I can say that the sensation is more pronounced than the taste. If you're trying to mimic freshly grated wasabi, you're going to have a harder task ahead of you, but the primary objective will be to find ingredients that have a clean aroma but have a marked pungency. Freshly grated western horseradish comes pretty close, though there is a difference.

Answer (score 8):

horseradish is a common substitute for wasabi.

Comment: Most of the "wasabi" that you can buy is not really wasabi, but a mixture of horseradish and other things.